# Add phone numbers to the same contact Android

Tags: java, android

I used a piece of code

```
    String DisplayName = "XYZ";
 String MobileNumber = "123456";
 String HomeNumber = "1111";
 String WorkNumber = "2222";
 String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
 String company = "bad";
 String jobTitle = "abcd";

 ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
 ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
     .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
     .build());

 //------------------------------------------------------ Names
 if (DisplayName != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
     ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
     DisplayName).build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number                     
 if (MobileNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
     newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
 if (HomeNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
 if (WorkNumber != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Email
 if (emailID != null) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
 if (!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals("")) {
     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
     ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
         .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
         .build());
 }

 // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                 
 try {
     getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

I found it here : [How to add new contacts in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744187/how-to-add-new-contacts-in-android)

My question is, how do I do to add multiple phone numbers under a single contact ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612029/add-one-contact-with-multiple-numbers-android-programmatically

Comment: yeah, you're right, thanks :)